# Send information via Parallel Port

Tags: linux, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I have a BarCode-Scanner and I need to get some information about it,
such as Serial Number.

The problem is that it communicates with the host via parallel port
(like a keyboard). I need to know how to send commands to the parallel port.

I've tried:

```
$ echo -n 'hexadecimal command' > /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
```

but that only get's trash!

does anybody have any idea how to send and read data from parallel port?
(it works just like a keyboard).

tks,

Comment: I've never heard of keyboard on parallel ports. Keyboards usually go on PS/2 or USB ports.

Comment: A link to the scanner's documentation, or at least a make and model would be helpful.

Comment: You've tagged this post with Serial-port but you use parallel port throughout the question. Please clarify the connection type.